# Creating elder magi

Tags: ars-magica-5

I'm going to need to stat up a few elder magi for my saga, but the sourcebooks are drastically short of guidelines for magi of the 100-150 years / archmage level.  I'm happy to wave my hands a bit for people outside the covenant, but the senior magi in the covenant need a fair quantity of stats; particularly since they're likely to have written a significant number of the texts in the library!

So, other than doing season-at-a-time (400 seasons!) what can be done?

Answer (score 4):

A good resource for building magi at various power levels is the [Magi of Hermes](http://www.atlas-games.com/product_tables/AG0292.php) book from Atlas Games.

It presents fifteen Magus characters, with backgrounds and story hooks, but also fully statted at several points in their life: right after their Gauntlet , 15 years later, 30, 60 or 75. It's both a good source of powerful NPCs and a good template for building them.

If you want magi even older than that (75 years active + 15 years of apprenticeship + ~8 years of childhood = ~100 years old), it shouldn't be a problem to check the differences in stats between, say, the +60 years and +75 years versions of the same character to see how much of a bump you should give. Keep in mind, of course, that it gets incredibly hard to raise scores at those ranges, so you should check out the differences between +30 to +45, +45 to +60 and +60 to +75 to see the average rate of *slowdown*, as well. Or just approximate and give a bump to the stats.

Comment: *Magi of Hermes* (which I'd entirely forgotten I had on my shelf) is a wonderful resource both for interesting NPCs and for ideas of interesting things you can do; but it's not a great resource for making other powerful magi -- the examples are too diverse and only some of them have points values give.  *But*  the approach of advancing characters 15 years at a time might well be a good one for the problem; as a balance between massive handwaving and the drudgery of a season at a time.

Comment: More examples are within the Atlas games forum posts which detail season by season advancement, which is by far the best way to get an accurate magus by age - they are worth reading. Advancing in approx values by point spend (say 1000 pt magus for +15 years out of apprenticeship) is fine for roughing NPCs, but there is a tangible difference between season by season vs bulk points spend in the detail and scaled power of a magus. If possible do it season by season.